# How to set grid kendo fields condionnally?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with columns like below:

```
 columns: [
        {
          title: 'Solde Débiteur',
          field: 'sold', // if sold > 0
          filterable: { cell: { operator: 'eq', showOperators: false } }
        },
        {
          title: 'Solde Créditeur',
          field: 'sold', // if sold < 0
          filterable: { cell: { operator: 'eq', showOperators: false } }
        }
]
```

how can populate my grid anf set sold in first column if it is positive and in the second if negative?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You should handle this in back end. Use different field names for both column, set condition on back end, bind appropriate columns.

Comment: i need something really fast because calling the service returing the datasource is taking so long

Answer (score 0):

You can use `template` to fill column conditionally. For example:

```
 columns: [
        {
          title: 'Solde Débiteur',
          field: 'sold', // if sold > 0
          filterable: { cell: { operator: 'eq', showOperators: false } },
          template: "<div>#= sold > 0 ? sold :0 #</div>" //if sold > 0 return sold else 0
        },
        {
          title: 'Solde Créditeur',
          field: 'sold', // if sold < 0
          filterable: { cell: { operator: 'eq', showOperators: false } }
          template: "<div>#= sold < 0 ? sold :0 #</div>" // if sold < 0 return sold else 0
        }
]
```